# 100% cpu usage on one core in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webcam, python-multithreading

I am doing a robotic project on raspberry pi in which i need frame from a webcam, attached to raspberry pi, continuously so i am extracting frames  from `videocapture()` in a separate thread than main program and saving the frames in a queue. The problem is that, when i run the program , initially CPU usage is normal i.e. 30-40 max in each core of pi but after a while CPU usage on one core reaches to 100 % while other 3 cores are less than 20% which slows down the program.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any related solution. I am not able to understand what the problem is, is it thread (`python` `GIL` problem) or there is something else. 
Any suggestions would be helpful.

These are the function in camera module which are getting the frame and saving in queue

```
self.framerate_ms = 1.0/float(20)
def start(self):
    if self.t:
        return

    f = None
    if self.camera_type == USB:
        f = self.update_usb

    self.t = Thread(target=f, args=())
    #self.t.daemon = True
    self.t.start()



def update_usb(self):
    while True:
        if self.stopped:
            return

        (grabbed, frame) = self.camera.read()

        if not grabbed:
            self.stop()
            return

        if self.Q.full():
            self.Q.get()

        self.Q.put(frame)            
        self.ready = True

        #sleep(self.framerate_ms)
```

ps sorry for bad English i am not native English speaker.

Comment: We probably can't help because we can see none of the code. We would need to see something representative that recreates the issue.

Comment: Hard to tell without a magic crystal ball that would allow us to catch a glimpse of the code. Best guess is that one of your threads enters a loop with no `time.sleep` (or any other call that would release the *CPU*) inside.

Comment: Thank for your response, i have updated the question

Comment: @CristiFati i've also tried adding sleep but that didnt help either

Comment: That doesn't help, provided code is not enough. Try to recreate the problem on your desktop/laptop, try to minimize it till it fits into the [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) specs, and then, if you still have the problem (although I doubt), update your question.